# Open access to a particular user for a particular field of a particular record

Tags: profile, user, permission-sets, field-level-security, custom-permission

A profile doesn't have access to any of the 5( Let's say A,B,C,D,E) fields in the object, however I have to allow a user in the profile to edit field A, that too for certain records.
Is it possible? How should I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Its a two step process.

1. Create a Permission set to provide access to those Fields and assign that permission to that user
2. Use manual sharing to share such specific records with your user.

Now the user has access to records as well as permission to view/edit those fields.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps:-
PS: the OWD is set to Private for that object then we can restrict him from viewing all records:

```
1. Create a permission set "Access A" : under "Object Settings" permission for object --> give permission to field "A" under Field Permission. Also give "Read, Create, Edit, Delete" permission for Object Permissions.
2. Assign the particular user with permission set "Access A".
3. Go to each account and click the button sharing to give access. Where click on Add button to select the user from available list.
```